# Concrete anchor distance from edge

Tags: concrete, deck

I've got a concrete pad in my backyard, installed by a previous owner.  I'd like to build a pergola on it.  The woodworking aspects of this project are entirely within my capabilities.

One thing that's outside of my wheelhouse is anchoring it to the concrete pad.  I can rent the appropriate drill and masonry bit - but I don't know how far in from the edge of the pad I need to drill.

What is the minimum distance marked `x` in the attached picture that I can drill?
[image: Concrete pad]

I will also accept a frame challenge here in the form of "Don't drill into the concrete, do YYY instead".

The linked question [Distance between edge of concrete for anchor bolts?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172115/distance-between-edge-of-concrete-for-anchor-bolts) uses terminology I'm unfamiliar with and seems to have something to do with walls.  I'm not able to take the information from there and synthesize an answer to my question.

Comment: This answer may help:
https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/172115/distance-between-edge-of-concrete-for-anchor-bolts

Comment: If you're using a post installed anchor, like a Simpson Titen HD, just google the screw type you have and they have pdfs online that list this info based on diameter and concrete embedment length. I'd assume you have 3,000 psi concrete.

Comment: The question isn't answerable with the information provided. Quantity, size, type, etc. is all critical information. There's no one magic number. Also describe your slab in more detail--thickness, age, reinforcement type....

Comment: You need thickness, rebar info- if used, and is it thicker at the edge. You could dig down at a spot on the edge and measure thickness.

Comment: Thanks @PJ8 - I found that answer before I posted this but it uses terminology that I am unfamiliar with.  I don't know what a sil plate is, and I'm having trouble understanding how the parts about walls apply to my problem.

I can dig down on the edge and figure out how thick the concrete is, but it's unlikely I'll be able to determine the age or the reinforcement type of the slab.  My best guess is that it was poured in 2012 when a different part of the house had an addition put on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by others in the comments above, there are a number of variables and the manufacturer of your fastener should have data tables available. I've included as an example only the data table for an anchor I will be using on my garage slab to anchor a metal post base. I believe the minimum distance from concrete edge is the "critical edge distance" in this table; for my application I am using a 1/2" size anchor, so would need to be at least 5" from an edge, and have a minimum spacing of 9 inches between anchors.
[image]